# UIBarButtonItemのタイトルを設定しつつシステムアイコンを表示したい

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()

    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "戻る", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back")        
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
}
```

上記のようなカタチでUIBarButtonItemのタイトルを変更するはできたのですが、この「戻る」の前によくある左矢印のシステムアイコンを表示して「<戻る」のようにしたいのですが、やり方がわからず困っています。

```
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play,  target: self, action: "back")
```

こちらを試した場合はタイトルを設定できずにアイコンしか変更できませんでした。

どなたか良き解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらぜひ教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "戻る", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
```

遷移元のViewControllerのNavigationBarに↑を設定すると、遷移した時に "<戻る" のようになります！

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

ですが、実は特殊事情で当該ViewController内でのみNavigationBarを使って、遷移先を含めた他箇所で使わない方向で実現したいと考えています。

逆にアプリ内すべてでNavigationを使用して当該コントローラー以外を非表示にして対応する方法も考えたのですが、できればこの方法で実現できれば、と思い質問させていただきました。

Comment: そうでしたか！であれば、やはり矢印の画像を用意してボタンを作ってそれを当該ViewControllerのNavigationBarにのせるしかないと思います！

Comment: そうですね、それで対応したいと思います。ありがとうございました！